# bash regex string replace in a single column within a csv

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a csv where I need to trim some text from a column probably using a regex. This is an example:

test.csv:

| Number | Text | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | the id is G11 (sometimes) | A |
| 2 | the id is G12 | B |
| 3 | the id is G15 | C |
| 4 | the id is Z13 (always) | D |

I want to only grab the code value like (G11, G12, G15, Z13) from the Text column and replace the value so that I would get:

| Number | Text | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G11 | A |
| 2 | G12 | B |
| 3 | G15 | C |
| 4 | Z13 | D |

I have tried using forms of grep, awk, and sed but haven't got anything to work. I'm unfamiliar with bash, but essentially I want a new csv that looks like table 2.

These are my attempts, unsure how to only work on the Test column....

```
sed 's/([A-Z]\d{2}).*/([A-Z]\d{2})' test.csv > test2.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E '1!s/([^a-z]*)[^A-Z]*([^ ]* )[^|]*/\1\2/'
```

| Number | Text | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G11 | A |
| 2 | G12 | B |
| 3 | G15 | C |
| 4 | Z13 | D |

`1!` - Do not match line 1

`([^a-z]*)` - Retain everything within the parenthesis up until the next occurrence of lower case letters which will later be returned with back reference `\1`.

`[^A-Z]*` - Exclude everything up till the next occurrence of capital letters as it is not captured within parenthesis.

`([^ ]* )` - Retain everything up to the next occurrence of a space and including a space which will later be returned with back reference `\2`.

`[^|]*` - Exclude everything up till the next occurrence of a pipe symbol

Anything not included in the find will be returned with the replacement.

Comment: What is the 1! do at the start? Also I need to get rid of the bracket (sometimes) and (always) in my final output

Comment: @lmmjrf Do not match line 1, so no modification is carried out on that line

Comment: @lmmjrf Is the bracket with the contents literally in your data? You can try this `sed -E '1!s/([^a-z]*)[^A-Z]*([^ ]* )[^|]*/\1\2/' input_file`